# How to copy the content of a a folder which its name is partially known in centos

Tags: linux, centos, cp

I have a folder which has another folder inside it (lets say test and insidetest-some random number). Now what I am trying to do is to copy the content of the insidetest-... into another folder. The problem is that I know half of the name of the folder which in test folder and I do not know the the randon number attached to it. (Just for more explanation I  get the a zip file from bitbucket api and then after unzip it it has this structure. So I can never know the exact name of the folder inside test. If I knew that I could simply use sth like this:

```
cp home/test/* /home/myfolder/
```

But I cannot do it in this situation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some part of the name is constant then use the command like this:-

cp home/test/halfname* /home/folder/ -r